# Too many arguments are assigned to the function?

Tags: c, visual-studio, arguments

I define a variable

```
wchar_t path[256];
```

Then I try to get the `strlen()` of this variable

```
strlen(path);
```

Error is `strlen()` too many arguments?

I don't understand, I am only passing 1 argument to `strlen()` and path is simple a char of size `WORD` that can span up to 256 characters?

What is the issue here? How can I circumvent it?

SOLVED!

To get around this I simply type casted the sPath wchar_t as a `(const BYTE *)` therefore it allowed me to read in ASCII which told the strlen() function to stop counting when it hits zero. Works now.

Comment: Something else I notice just reading through the man pages. It says to use wcslen for wide characters. It is the same as strlen, just on wide characters.

Comment: @Evan same deal, wcslen also says there are too many arguments.

Comment: Please post your whole code (i.e. function or block), it seems your problem is elsewhere, probably a syntax error.

Comment: Insure `#include <string.h>` occurs before `strlen(path)`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [`wcslen`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/wide/wcslen) function (defined in the header `<wchar.h>`), which takes a `const wchar_t *str`  as argument, while [`strlen`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strlen) expects a `const char *str`.

Comment: @user3267146 [it works here](https://ideone.com/M1NyYA). Maybe you should post the rest of your code.

Answer (score 0):

strlen() looks for a '\0' in the supplied string. Which is a null terminating string. If you pass it an uninitialized string it may look forever because who knows whats in the memory before you put something there. Which to continue means strlen() looks till it finds '\0' which if there is no '\0' it won't stop it'll read all the memory it can, should produce a endless loop.

Try putting:

```
char path[256] = {"test"};
```

Pass that, it auto null terminates in that case.

Comment: How is that related to the error message `too many arguments`?

Comment: You need to check that something is in the array. If you have never assigned any values in the array it will look for the '\0' forever, it may check for that and say, "too many arguments."

Comment: Okay, thanks for clearing that up, but how exactly do I change this? Should I write my own function for strlen() in this scenerio using wide characters instead?

Comment: path[0] = '\0'; and then pass it see what happens.

Comment: What you are saying makes no sense to me.

Comment: @AbstractDonut The error wouldn't be `too many arguments` in that case, but probably a Segmentation Fault, since the function would try to access memory out of the allocated buffer.

Comment: If that is not what's happening we need him to write more of his code.